# Technical name when professor decrease the numerator.

Tags: statistics

When a professor re-size the class's mean and standard deviation, this is called curving the grade. I was wonder what the technical name is when the professor decrease the total number of possible points. In other words, let's suppose the exam is to be out of 120. Now, it's out of 100 with 120 possible points.

Edit: If there is no technical name, how about a technical description of this transformation. I know it's at least rank preserving.

Comment: "Allowing extra credit."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works out to "multiplying everybody's grade by 1.2", so you probably want *rescaling*.